# A vampire book from a while ago?

Tags: story-identification, books, vampire

I read this story many years ago. It was a vampire book that focused on a family, I believe. Drinking human blood wasn't required. The protagonist's grandmother brought him tiger's blood because it was his favorite. The mother bought blood at a regular store, the cold cases slid away and there was racks of blood available for purchase.

Comment: How long is "many years"? Did you read this book in English? What part of the world was it set in (e.g. was it India, or somewhere tiger's blood would have to be imported?) Was it set in the modern day or in older times? Was it a novel or a short story? Part of a series? *Any* extra details you can remember might help someone to find the book for you. You might also like to browse the [checklists](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) to see if anything jogs your memory.